# CSS grid column width: not working in Firefox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

[image]My outer grid has two columns; the upper right cell contains another grid which as 3 square cells.

In Firefox the inner grid (yellow) horizontally spans the whole container, thus taking more space than its children. In Chrome it's working as expected.

I tried using `grid-auto-columns: min-content` etc., but no difference.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 80vmin / 10vmin auto;
  grid-template-areas: "left right";
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
  display: flex;
}

.inner-grid {
  background: yellow;
  display: grid;
}

.inner-grid>.grid-item {
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.inner-grid>.grid-item:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="inner-grid">
    <svg class="grid-item" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <foreignObject height="100%" width="100%">
        <div>1</div>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
    <svg class="grid-item" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <foreignObject height="100%" width="100%">
        <div>2</div>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
    <svg class="grid-item" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <foreignObject height="100%" width="100%">
        <div>3</div>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Appears that Chrome and Firefox have a different layout sequence. FF lays out the 3 square cells at full width, establishing the width of the container, and *then* applies `display: flex`, which lays out the squares in a column, but doesn't resize the container. Chrome handles the process more intuitively. Again, that's what it seems to me. Perhaps `flex-basis: 0` on `.inner-grid` can work for you.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Thanks! `flex-basis: 0` indeed is working. Only now `.inner-grid` has zero width, thus I can't set a border that spans the content, which would be nice... Also, in Chrome `flex-basis: content` is working as intended, but not in Firefox.